# Google analytics on one site with different domains

Tags: google-analytics

We how a site that is accessible from two different domains. let it be original.com and new.com

We have such sript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-*******-**']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'original.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);



  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

The problem is that in GA I see sessions from origina.com but I don't see sessions from new.com

How should I modify code above to be able to see sessions from both domains in one Google Analytics View?

UPDATE

Both domains has points to one app by main damain and to another app by subdomain. So original.com and new.com point to one app and sub.original.com and sub.new.com point to another app.

I need to see both original.com and new.com in one view and sub.original.com and sub.new.com in another view

Comment: Are  you redirecting from original to new? Do you have the  same  code on new? Are you  doing cross domain tracking?

Comment: Quite a while since I used the asychronous GA code, but IIRC _setDomainname must be set to "none" if you are doing cross domain tracking (and if you want to track the domains individually you should drop t that line entirely). And you should migrate to the Universal Analytics tracking code (it's all UA in the background now in any case).

Comment: @EikePierstorff Both of domains have same subdomains. Will "none" option let us get data from subdomains?

Comment: @nyuen both domains point to the same app. The problem is I don't know how to route tracked data from two domains to one GA view as this view has Website URL set to old domain and seems like this URL is kind of filter that selects which data to add to this GA view